# InvalidCredentialsException while accessing Google Calendar

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I have developed a java application which uses the google calendar api to access the calendar. 
Application code is follow:

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("mail@gmail.com", "pass");
```

But I can't access to calendar. Method `setUserCredentials(username, password)` throws `InvalidCredentialsException`.
Email and password is correct. For example, I tried use Firefox Poster - for users Get queries - working correctly. If I tried use Java application - I have exception `InvalidCredentialsException`.
May be anybody know why method throws authorization error?

So, Exception:

```
com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:660)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
```